# How to add a custom redirect rule for Post as subdomains?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am trying to write a custom redirect rule to open a download matching pages.

```
Example: postname.example.com/download
Example2: postname.es.example.com/download
```

I am using the following code in my functions.php:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)\.example\.com/download?$','index.php?pagename=download&postnames=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)\es.example\.com/download?$','index.php?language=es&pagename=download&postnames=$matches[1]','top');
```

I've also added wildcard forwarding for all subdomains from my DNS and verified.
but these rule not work can please help me out how open my download page like this